# How do you lock specific folders in Windows 7 without having to specify user privileges?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, user-profiles, privileges

I have an external hard drive hooked up to my Windows 7 machine, and I would like to lock a folder with a password so that nobody can access it through my computer (or any other USB-connected machine) without knowing that password. Otherwise, I would like to keep all the other data public.

I have only 1 user account on my system and I would prefer to keep it that way. Is there any way to lock a folder despite which user is logged on?

I'm not sure if my question is phrased correctly, so feel free to edit based on my description.

Comment: The only way to do that would be through some kind of third party software, which means you'd need to install that software on any machine you planned on hooking up to the device as well.

Comment: As in, there may be 3rd party software that would encrypt just that one folder, and the only key to opening it would be on my machine? Because that would work great.

Comment: Yeah, I'll look at some stuff I've used before and see if I can provide a decent answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

Edited to add: TrueCrypt is no longer considered secure. See the link for migration instructions.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to lock up a folder with a password I use winrar and add a password. Just install and right click on the folder you want to password click on "add to archive" and go to the "advanced" tab and click on set password. Click OK and then click OK to make the archive then delete the original folder or file you now have a password on your personal file.